# Recursive Sierpinski triangle in Java?

Tags: java

I need to create a program that draws a Sierpinski triangle of order n. To do this, I have a few methods. Height, filledTriangle, and sierpinski. I made some progress in printing triangles recursively in the bottom left, but now that I'm trying to create triangles to the right and up things aren't working out. I think my problem lies in the filledTriangle method, as I'm not sure how to accommodate all the triangles with different vertexes.

```
public class Sierpinski {

    // Height of an equilateral triangle whose sides are of the specified length. 
    public static double height(double length) {

        double height = length * Math.sqrt(3.0)/2;

        return height;

    }

    // Draws a filled equilateral triangle whose bottom vertex is (x, y) 
    // of the specified side length. 
    public static void filledTriangle(double x, double y, double length) {

        double x2 = x - x/2;
        double y2 = y + height(length)/2;

        double x3 = x + (x/2);
        double y3 = y + height(length)/2;

        double[] xx = {x, x2, x3};
        double[] yy = {y, y2, y3};

        StdDraw.filledPolygon(xx, yy);

    }

    // Draws a Sierpinski triangle of order n, such that the largest filled 
    // triangle has bottom vertex (x, y) and sides of the specified length. 
    public static void sierpinski(int n, double x, double y, double length)
    {
        filledTriangle(x, y, length);

        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println("Done!");
        } else {
            filledTriangle(x, height(length)/2, length/2);
                x = x/2;
                length = length/2;
            filledTriangle(x, y, length);
            filledTriangle(3*x, y, length);
            n--;
            sierpinski(n, x, y, length);               
        }

    }

    // Takes an integer command-line argument n; 
    // draws the outline of an equilateral triangle (pointed upwards) of length 1; 
    // whose bottom-left vertex is (0, 0) and bottom-right vertex is (1, 0); and 
    // draws a Sierpinski triangle of order n that fits snugly inside the outline. 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = 1;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double t = Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;
        StdDraw.line(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        StdDraw.line(1.0, 0.0, 0.5, height(length));
        StdDraw.line(0.5, height(length), 0.0, 0.0);

        double x = 0.5;
        double y = 0;

        sierpinski(n, x, y, length);

    }
}
```

A Sierpinski triangle of order 3 should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dzJm.jpg
My output is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHx0f.jpg

Comment: I managed to get it to at least draw correctly by changing `x2` in `filledTriangle` to `x - length / 4` and `x3` to `x + length / 4`. The overall shape of the triangle is still wrong though.

Comment: @Lignum https://imgur.com/a/2eSbiCY That appeared to fix the general shape of the triangles, but they are only repeated in the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this method:

```
public static void sierpinski(int n, double x, double y, double length)
{
    filledTriangle(x, y, length);

    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println("Done!");
    } else {
        filledTriangle(x, height(length)/2, length/2);
            x = x/2;
            length = length/2;
        filledTriangle(x, y, length);
        filledTriangle(3*x, y, length);
        n--;
        sierpinski(n, x, y, length);               
    }

}
```

You are passing a decreased `n` and a halved `length` to `sierpinski`, but you do not change `x` and `y`. This is not a good approach. It would be much better to pass the coordinates of the "current" triangle and you will know that at each time there will be 3x as many triangles to be drawn. You would need to call `sierpinski` 3 times each time (except when the process has to end) a `sierpinski` triangle was drawn. You have only one sierpinski call, which explains why the number of triangles doesn't increase threefold on each depth. You should thing coordinates of triangle points and know that the half of each side will be a point in the next depth.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed up the code to this: https://imgur.com/a/R0DzJYN Here's the output: imgur.com/a/fR9M1h0 Definitely a step in the right direction, but some of the triangles are off.

Comment: @MaxJacobs if we assume that you have three points, A, B and C, then you can know that exactly at the half of the line of each two of the three points (A, B), (A, C) and (B, C) you have new points in the next step. In the next step the new points will have half the distance as the current step and the sides of the new triangles will be parallel with the sides of the old triangle.

Comment: @MaxJacobs the equation of a line is Y - Y1 = (X - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1). (except in the case of horizontal lines, which have an equation of X = c). Now, if you know that you have a line drawn on two earlier points, P1(X1, Y1) and P2(X2, Y2) and you have a new point, P3(X3, Y3), which is not collinear with the P1P2 line, but parallel with it, then: if it's not a horizontal line, then the other point of it, P4 is on the line which contains P3 and is parallel with the line of P1P2.

Comment: @MaxJacobs So, But we know that d^2 = (X4 - X3)^2 + (Y4 - Y3)^2, so you will get a circle with a radius of d (which is half of the previous length). The center of this circle is P3 and it has exactly two points on the circle which, with P3 would form a line parallel with P1P2. Since we are searching for parallel points, we know that (Y4 - Y3) / (X4 - X3) = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1), so we can use the latter: Y - Y3 = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) * (X - X3).  Y = Y3 + (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) * (X - X3). You can use this formula in the circle equation to determine X and Y.

Comment: @MaxJacobs if the line is horizontal, then you have a simple case, where you know the exact length which will be added/subtracted from the X coordinate.

Comment: @MaxJacobs alternatively you can work with trigonometrical functions, calculating the points' relative location from the center of a circle which has your previous point as its center, scale it with length/2 and finally translate it with your original x, y coordinate to "move" it to its proper location.